# How to handle interruption in dialogs with validation?

Tags: c#, botframework

Attempt to handle 'expected' interruption during one scenario is ignored in favour of validating the user input.

I've got a bot (SDKv4) with 3 distinct scenarios. I've extracted each scenario into their own class inheriting from `ComponentDialog`. Here, I can contain all waterfall steps relevant for each scenario.

```cs
public class ScenarioOne : ComponentDialog
{
    public ScenarioOne()
    {
        var steps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            GetInputStepAsync,
            ProcessInputStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(ScenarioOne), steps));
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetInputStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Prompt for data here.
    }
}
```

In one scenario, I require a 17-character input from the user. I applied a custom validator and assigned it to the relevant waterfall step.

```cs
public class StepOneValidator
{
    public async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Validation logic here.
    }
}
```

The validator is registered in the Bot:

```cs
public ExampleBot(ExampleBotAccessors accessors)
{
    _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessor.Dialog);
    _dialogs
        .Add(new TextPrompt("step-one", new CustomValidator().ValidateAsync));

    _dialogs.Add(new ScenarioOne());
}
```

I'd like to handle expected interruption for this specific scenario such as `more info` or `help` to assist users with the format of the expected input. I've read from the documentation that I can intercept the response globally within the `OnTurnAsync` handler but this will be applied to *all* responses which I'd like to avoid.

Documentation that I'm following can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharptab#handle-expected-interruptions).

Something similar can be added to the `ProcessInputStepAsync` method to check for expected interruptions:

```cs
public async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessInputStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = ((string)stepContext.Result).Trim().ToLowerInvariant();
    if (response.Equals("help")
    {
        // Send activity and replace dialog with main dialog.
    }
}
```

I expect the validator to ignore expected interruptions. Is there a way to achieve this without hard-coding these in the validator?

Comment: Do you want the interruptions globally for the bot or just for your `ScenarioOne` dialog?

Comment: Only for the `ScenarioOne` dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `OnContinueDialogAsync` method on `ComponentDialog` and do your interruption logic there. As part of your checks, you can see what the active dialog is and if it is your `TextInput` then handle your interruption. An example is below.

```
public class ScenarioOne : ComponentDialog
{
    private static string textInputId = "text";

    public ScenarioOne()
    {
        var steps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            GetInputStepAsync,
            ProcessInputStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(ScenarioOne), steps));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(textInputId));
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetInputStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Prompt for data here.
    }

    protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        string text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text;

        if (text.ToLower() == "help" && innerDc.ActiveDialog.Id != textInputId)
        {
            //do interruption
        }
        return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Could you also please add the missing async/await in your protected method?